# OnClientClick event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the webpage I'm building, I have a div that I need to have hidden by default, and for it to appear when the user clicks on a link button. This is the code for the link button and the following div:

```
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Words & stuff go here"
        OnClientClick="button_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

    <div id="Calculator" runat="server" visible="false">
        //CODE GOES IN HERE 
    </div>
```

And here is the code in the cs file for the link button:

```
void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Calculator.Visible)
            Calculator.Visible = false;

        else if (!Calculator.Visible)
            Calculator.Visible = true;
    }
```

I have a breakpoint inside the code behind, and when I debug, the breakpoint is never reached, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property of an ASP .NET control references a client-side function, which means that it will attempt to call a JavaScript function.

You have two options to fix your code.

Option 1:
If you want the button to do a [Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183254/what-is-a-postback) and call your `button_Click` function in your `.cs` file, you could just change your button code to:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Words & stuff go here" OnClick="button_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Option 2:
If you wish to use [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx), you could do something similar to the following (in your `.aspx` file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function button_Click() {
  var calculator_id = '<%= Calculator.ClientID %>';
  var calculator = document.getElementById(calculator_id);
  if (calculator.style.display == 'none') {
    calculator.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    calculator.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Originally trying to use an OnClick event gave me an error when having the button_Click event in the code behind, but after putting it in th aspx file in a script tag, using the OnClick in place of the OnClientClick works perfectly, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

on client click is for client side events. You have to use onClick="button_Click" to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`OnClientClick` expects that the button_Click event is defined in javascript on the page, not in C# in the code-behind.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx).