# Trying to trigger postback on MVC dropdownlist in VB .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html-select

This is my code in SearchResults View for the colours dropdownlist

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("colours", TryCast(ViewData("colours"), SelectList),
                       New With {.onchange = "document.getElementById('wineSearchCriteria').submit();"})</td>
```

I've set the form name to 'wineSearchCriteria'

```
<form action="/Wines/SearchResults" method="post" name="wineSearchCriteria"
    input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

but the form is not posting back when the colours dropdown is changed. I'm sure this will be something simple!

Comment: Just as a bit of info. A [postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183254/what-is-a-postback/183481#183481) is very much a Webforms concept. MVC is more tightly coupled to HTTP so it's either a [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) or a [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` will only retrieve elements by their ID, but you are not assigning an ID to the form. You are assigning a name to the form. Use the `id` attribute instead:

```
<form action="/Wines/SearchResults" method="post" id="wineSearchCriteria"
input type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Charlie - as I said I knew it had to be something simple! Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the id attribute as `"wineSearchCriteria"`, not the name.

```
<form action="/Wines/SearchResults" method="post" id="wineSearchCriteria" />
```