# Page redirection not hitting break points in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a survey application which user fills the info and then clicks Submit and gets redirected to other page(`Success.aspx`) which simply shows a message
"Survey was saved!"

After that I want to redirect user automatically to the login page. I found the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=Login.aspx/" />
```

Above code "Does" work. User gets redirected to `login.aspx` after 3 seconds, however code does not break in Visual Studio(2013) anymore. If user tries to login, code directs him to the survey page `Response.Redirect("Survey.aspx")`

but the break point that I put in the load even of that page will no longer works.

If I remove

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=Login.aspx/" />
```

Breakpoints work again! Is this a known issue?

Comment: What's the HTTP response code you get? Are you sure your browser isn't caching the response?

Comment: Not sure but the this behavior is exact cause of adding `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=Login.aspx/" />`

Comment: How to check the HTTP response? how to check if browser i caching?

Comment: I'd advise installing [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and inspecting the HTTP to get a better understaning of what is happening. I would bet the HTTP request has a cache header and the browser is serving it from it's cache and therefore not hitting the server/your instance of VS

Comment: As far as the server is concerned, they are two entirely independent requests. It's not even a redirect in any real sense. Does VS normally honor breakpoints like that?

Comment: @cHao: Yes, breakpoints will all hit if I remove `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=Login.aspx/" />'

Comment: @SNash: ...? Even the ones in `Login.aspx`?

Comment: After `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=Login.aspx/" />` Breakpoints in the login.aspx are hit. But breakpoints in the Survey.aspx will no longer hit.

Comment: So where are your breakpoints? In login.aspx or survey.aspx?

Comment: Both locations. the ones in login.aspx hit , the ones in survey do not get hit.

Comment: Well in that case that is correct functionality. The redirect never sends a request to login.aspx, your thinking of postbacks, your not triggering a postback you're triggering a new request (to **login.aspx**) to a different page! Entirely different thing. You can't trigger a postback using a meta tag, you'd need to use javascript

Comment: Yes I, use Javascript and it works.

Comment: I am still confused  on why  using <meta http-equiv="refresh"  breakpoints are hit in login.aspx but not in survey.aspx.

Comment: @ Liam, based on your logic, breakpoints in the login.aspx  also should not be hit. Or I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, your wrong :) You need to understand the difference between a [postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183254/what-is-a-postback) which ASP.Net does when you press a button and a [HTTP Request](http://rve.org.uk/dumprequest) which is what the meta tag is doing.

Comment: @Liam, put this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused between a [ASP.Net postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183254/what-is-a-postback) and a classic [HTTP Request](http://rve.org.uk/dumprequest) (in this case a [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods))

Only ASP.Net does a postback, this is a none standard interaction triggered by a [__doPostback() JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback) call that comes bundled into ASP.Net.

What the meta tag does is a standard HTTP GET.

The difference (in your particular scenario) is that the postback will hit the calling page when something happens (the client triggers a HTTP POST to the server and ASP.Net handles the call) where as the meta will simply trigger a GET to the new page (the client simply calls the new page and does not interact with the calling page)

Hope that explains it.