# How to populate dropdown list with parameters ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page with some inputs. 
In one hand, i have the following two inputs to capture the range of dates:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="bDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="eDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

and, at the bottom of the page, I have a dropdown that should be filled with a query like

```
select xxx from table where beginDate >= bDate and endDate <= eDate
```

The goal is to have this dropdown correctly populated with no need to click on any button.

PS: I have all the code on page load and the query correctly running (only select) so I should only want to know the 
knowledge to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnTextChanged="DateTextChanged_OnTextChanged"` on one (or both) of your textbox if both have value.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="bDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date" OnTextChanged="DateTextChanged_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="eDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date" OnTextChanged="DateTextChanged_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Then validate they have value in your code behind if they do call the business logic to get information to bind to your dropdown list.

```
protected void DateTextChanged_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do validation run query     
}
```

NOTE: This with post back will reload the screen so your probably want to use an update panel or something similar.

hope that helps

Comment: it works! thanks, i did not know the atriute onTextChanged

Comment: @user2662073 great to hear! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a DropDownList called ddlSubject, you must do:

```
var query = select xxx from table where beginDate >= bDate and endDate <= eDate

ddlSubject.DataSource = query ;
ddlSubject.DataTextField = "SubjectNamne";
ddlSubject.DataValueField = "SubjectID";
ddlSubject.DataBind();
```

And be careful if is or isn't a PostBack process: [What is a postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183254/what-is-a-postback)

Because this can clean completely your DropDownList.